# Windows 10 Home won't activate after clean reinstallation. Error 0x8007232B "DNS name does not exist"

Tags: windows-activation, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10

I bought my laptop last summer, and it came with Windows 8.1. I did an upgrade to Windows 10 Home edition today with the ISO using the media creation tool, and it was activated.

I then did a clean install just to wipe everything clean because it's been a while. Afterwards, it was activated for a couple of hours, but now it's saying that it's not activated anymore. When I try to activate it, I always get `Error code: 0x8007232B. Error Description: DNS name does not exist`

I'm posting from the laptop so Internet works

Update: I plugged the laptop directly into the modem via Ethernet, and the error changed to `Error code: 0x8007007B. Error description: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`...

Comment: Well, first things first: **is your Internet connection working?** Can you browse the web, ping hosts by name, etc. from the affected system?

Comment: Yes the internet works. I'm posting from the laptop

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make that clear, then.

Comment: I should point out that Microsoft's activation servers are having lots of troubles.  So unless you have other problems with the internet, it likely, isn't you.

Comment: It worked on my desktop 3 times no problems. It still wouldn't work today on my laptop, until after I reinstalled. I tried right before I reinstalled too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just doing a clean reinstall because I found out I installed Windows in BIOS mode instead of UEFI. Fixed everything, but I still don't know what caused it to begin with...

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing somehow your DNS settings got removed/changed.

Run a Command Prompt as Administrator (windows key -> "command prompt" -> right click -> Run As Administrator).

Then type in:

netsh interface ip set dns "Wi-Fi" static 8.8.8.8

If you use Wi-Fi. If you are wired, do:

netsh interface ip set dns "Local Area Connection" static 8.8.8.8

That will set your DNS server to Google's public DNS servers.

Comment: Changed DNS to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 in the IPv4 settings of the wireless adapter, and it still says the same thing

Comment: Note that OP clarified (just after you posted your answer, so I'm not downvoting) in a comment that the Internet connection is working fine.